# Criteria for convergence of power series

Tags: functions, convergence-divergence, power-series

Given the power series: $\; \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n \;$ Proof that if there exist $s,M \in \mathbb R $ such that $|a_n|s^n \le M$ then the power series converges for every $|z|\lt s$

Can someone give me a hint on how to proof this statement ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $|z|<s$ then$$
|a_n\,z^n|\le|a_n|\Bigl(\frac{|z|}{s}\Bigr)^ns^n\le M\Bigl(\frac{|z|}{s}\Bigr)^n
$$
with $|z|/s<1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That basically solved it (;